# Multi-column table sort with custom ordering for each column

Tags: python

I have a multi-column table of data, each row unique, and I want to know how to sort it based on multiple columns. If sorting alphabetically a solution is already described [here](http://www.saltycrane.com/blog/2007/12/how-to-sort-table-by-columns-in-python/). However, instead of alphabetical sorting, I need to sort each column based on a custom ordering stored in another list. For example, if my table is

```
mytable = [
    ('A1', 'B1', 'C1'),
    ('A1', 'B2', 'C2'),
    ('A2', 'B2', 'C1'),
    ('A2', 'B2', 'C2')
]
```

I might want the first column to be ordered ['A2','A1'], the second column to be ordered ['B1','B2'], and the third column to be ordered ['C2','C1']. The proper result would be

```
mytable = [
    ('A2', 'B2', 'C2'),
    ('A2', 'B2', 'C1'),
    ('A1', 'B1', 'C1'),
    ('A1', 'B2', 'C2')
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do what you're looking for:

```
orderings = (
    ('A2', 'A1'),
    ('B1', 'B2'),
    ('C2', 'C1')
)

orders = [dict([(v, i) for i, v in enumerate(o)]) for o in orderings]

mytable.sort(key=lambda r: tuple(o[c] for c, o in zip(r, orders)))
```

In practice, the columns might not all be sorted, or might be sorted in a priority other than left-right order. That could be solved by attaching an index to each and adapting the algorithm accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Python sorts tuples lexicographically by default.  This means all you need to do is to write a key function that returns a tuple again.  Example code:

```
order_a = {"A1": 1, "A2": 0}
order_b = {"B1": 0, "B2": 1}
order_c = {"C1": 1, "C2": 0}

def key(t):
    return order_a[t[0]], order_b[t[1]], order_c[t[2]]

mytable.sort(key=key)
```

(I used dictionaries instead of lists to define the order here, because this will result in better performance for large sets of possible values.)

Comment: Note that this would have to be extended for tables that have more than 3 columns

Comment: @DavidRobinson: I decided to focus on the actual issue.  Of course you need loops or something equivalent to generalise this from 3 to n, but this is not the question.

Comment: I think it's clear from the examples of "A1", "A2", etc that this isn't the actual use case!

Comment: I suppose my solution also has the problem that it assumes the columns should be sorted in the same priority as their left-right order.

Comment: @DavidRobinson: This is not relevant.  The OP asked for a *concept*, and our answers both show the concept.  This needs to be adapted to the actual use case anyway.

Comment: Sven - Question on runtime for your solution: do you know if the number of passes through the table in your solution is fewer than if you defined a similar function that sorted by one column at a time? For instance, if you were sorting by columns A, B, and C, you could custom sort by C, then by B, and then by A to get the desired result. If instead your use your exact approach, where the key function returns a tuple, does Python ultimately do less work?

Comment: @Abiel: Python would do less comparisons using a single sort compared to multiple sorts, since it only needs to compare elements in the columns further to the right in case of ties in the earlier columns.  If this indeed results in better performance depends on your actual code, and the only way to find out is to measure.